# lsof always report offset equal to file size in OSX

Tags: c, macos, scala, filesystems, lsof

I've tried to estimate, how much of the file my program has processed, and for me an obvious solution was to use `lsof -o`. But surprisingly, `OFFSET` in `lsof`'s output was always equal to SIZE (like in `lsof -s --`), so I decided to write some simple programs to test that behaviour, and...

**C:**

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int filedesc = open("path/to/file", O_RDONLY);
  printf("%i\n", filedesc);
  while(1) {};
}
```

**Scala:**

```
io.Source.fromFile(path)
```

**Python:**

```
open(path)
```

OFFSET was always at the end of file under OS X:

```
$ lsof -o /path/to/file
COMMAND  PID  USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE    OFFSET     NODE NAME
a.out   5390 folex    3r   REG    1,4 631302648 48453926 /path/to/file

$ lsof -s -- /path/to/file
COMMAND  PID  USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE      SIZE     NODE NAME
a.out   5390 folex    3r   REG    1,4 631302648 48453926 /path/to/file
```

Any explanations for each of these languages would be much appreciated.

**UPDATE**: Works as expected under Ubuntu. Wrong offset only under OS X.

Comment: None of your snippets move the offset from position 0. Are you sure you're interpreting the output of `lsof` correctly? Copy-paste it into your question. Also look at the data reported by the kernel (and copy that into your question as well), it's what `lsof` uses: `/proc/<PID>/<FD>/fdinfo`

Comment: just found out that under linux it works fine :( So it's OS X and lsof interop fault.

Comment: The C example: `open()` returns a file descriptor for the opened file. It tells you nothing about the file size. I recommend reading manual pages.

Comment: `lsof -s --` gives me file size and `lsof -o` gives descriptor offset. Snippets have nothing to do with file size.

Comment: Can you show a small sample of the output that you're seeing?

Comment: @user3386109 added `lsof -o` and `lsof -s --` output to question.

Comment: It's the same under WSL which makes me suspect that sort of data is not available due to kernel limitations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what the OSX man page says about the size/offset column for `lsof` (emphasis added):

> SIZE, SIZE/OFF, or OFFSET is the size of the file or the  file  offset
>   in  bytes. A value  is  displayed in this column only if it is
>   available. Lsof displays whatever value - size or offset - is
>   appropriate for the type of the file and the version of lsof. **On  some
>   UNIX dialects lsof can't obtain accurate or consistent file offset
>   information from its kernel  data  sources**, [...]
>
> The  file  size  is displayed in decimal; the offset is normally
>   displayed in decimal with a leading '0t' if it  contains 8 digits or
>   less; in hexadecimal with a leading '0x' if it is longer than 8
>   digits. [...]
>
> Thus the leading '0t' and '0x' identify an  offset  when the  column
>   may contain both a size and an offset (i.e., its title is SIZE/OFF).

Although the column heading says OFFSET, the number doesn't have the leading `'0t'` or `'0x'`, so I would conclude that the file offset information is simply not available from the OSX kernel.